# How could one show xtick labels in multiple lines?

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart, ticks

I have the following code for my bar chart.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\pgfplotsset{width=14cm,compat=1.9}
\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&]{
    Category&2007&2008&2009\\
        CSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS  & 29 & 22   & 32 \\
        CROsssssssssssssssssss & 20 & 11   & 14\\
        NCO & 23 & 20   & 28\\
        Ph  & 13 & 23   & 10 \\
        IS  & 52 & 32   & 38 \\
        L   & 8  & 21   & 11 \\
        NUK & 4  & 7    & 9 \\
        IS1  & 52 & 32   & 33\\
        L1  & 8  & 21   & 11 \\
        NUK1 & 4  & 7    & 9 \\
}\mydata


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar,
symbolic x coords={CSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS,CROsssssssssssssssssss,NCO,Ph,IS,L,NUK,IS1,L1,NUK1},
x tick label style={align=center},
xtick=data,
% reduce height of axis a bit
height=9cm,
% set width of bars
bar width=4pt,
% remove gap below bars
ymin=0,
enlarge x limits=.3,
% remove frame around legend, add some space
legend style={draw=none,column sep=2mm},
legend columns=2,
% customize how the legend images are drawn
% draw a square instead of two bars
legend image code/.code={%
       \draw[#1,draw=none,/tikz/.cd,yshift=-0.25em]
        (0cm,1pt) rectangle (6pt,7pt);},
% color map from colorbrewer
cycle list/Paired,
% the above only sets the color, need to specify that bars should be filled
every axis plot/.append style={fill}
]
\addplot table[x=Category,y=2007]{\mydata};
\addplot table[x=Category,y=2008]{\mydata};
\addplot table[x=Category,y=2009]{\mydata};


\legend{2007,2008,2009}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get the output like

[image]

The xlabels CSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS,CROsssssssssssssssssss are overlapping. How do I separate them in multiple lines so that they do not overlap?

Comment: You can rotate them: `xticklabel style={rotate=90,anchor=east}`.

Comment: I want them to be split in multiple lines rather than rotating. Like cssss in one line,then in next -ssssss.. How do I do that?

Comment: Thank you that works well. But, I need to still add spaces between the groups of bars. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to, introduce spaces the breaking points and set some `text width`. I did not have the patience to tune the width till all `\underfull` and `\overfull` complaints disappeared.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\pgfplotsset{width=14cm,compat=1.9}
\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&]{
    Category&2007&2008&2009\\
        CSS SSS SSS SSS SSS SSS SSS SSS & 29 & 22   & 32 \\
        CRO sss sss sss sss sss sss s & 20 & 11   & 14\\
        NCO & 23 & 20   & 28\\
        Ph  & 13 & 23   & 10 \\
        IS  & 52 & 32   & 38 \\
        L   & 8  & 21   & 11 \\
        NUK & 4  & 7    & 9 \\
        IS1  & 52 & 32   & 33\\
        L1  & 8  & 21   & 11 \\
        NUK1 & 4  & 7    & 9 \\
}\mydata

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar,
symbolic x coords={CSS SSS SSS SSS SSS SSS SSS SSS,CRO sss sss sss sss sss sss s,%
NCO,Ph,IS,L,NUK,IS1,L1,NUK1},
x tick label style={align=center},
xtick=data,
% reduce height of axis a bit
height=9cm,
% set width of bars
bar width=4pt,
% remove gap below bars
ymin=0,
enlarge x limits=.12,
% remove frame around legend, add some space
legend style={draw=none,column sep=2mm},
legend columns=2,
% customize how the legend images are drawn
% draw a square instead of two bars
legend image code/.code={%
       \draw[#1,draw=none,/tikz/.cd,yshift=-0.25em]
        (0cm,1pt) rectangle (6pt,7pt);},
% color map from colorbrewer
cycle list/Paired,
% the above only sets the color, need to specify that bars should be filled
every axis plot/.append style={fill},
xticklabel style={align=center,text width=6mm}
]
\addplot table[x=Category,y=2007]{\mydata};
\addplot table[x=Category,y=2008]{\mydata};
\addplot table[x=Category,y=2009]{\mydata};


\legend{2007,2008,2009}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]